# Configuration issue in behat

Tags: symfony, behat

I use behat v3.0.15 and i want to put my features in the ./app/features reposistory.

As i can read in the documentation http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/6.profiles.html#custom-autoloading all i have to do is to add theses lines in my behat.yml file

```
 # behat.yml

 default:
     autoload:
         '': %paths.base%/app/features/bootstrap
```

Sadly it doesn't work

When i try to init behat with this command `./bin/behat --config ./app/config/behat.yml --init`, the program creates a features folder under the config folder.

So what can i do?

Comment: If your config file is in `app/config` then I think you autoload should be `%paths.base%/../features/bootstrap`, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured autoloader. Location of features is configured in [`paths` section](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/6.profiles.html#custom-autoloading).

```
default:
    autoload: %paths.base%/app/features/bootstrap
    suites:
        default:
            paths:
                - %paths.base%/app/features
```

Configuration of [paths](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html?highlight=paths#suite-paths) and [autoloader](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/6.profiles.html#custom-autoloading) is documented on different pages, so it's confusing. [Behat 2.5 documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#paths) is little better (but yaml structure is different).

*Example is taken from [feature test for custom paths](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/dc6df78862e1c1e1faa7bffd396d7c3179d6749d/features/init.feature#L17)*

Comment: Isn't it  : paths: [ %paths.base%/app/features ]

Comment: It's only shorter syntax for [arrays](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections). Both notations should work the same way. I mixed example from github code and paths documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define your customized php featureContext files:

autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        -